# which statement is correct "for what I understand" or "from what I understand"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I know this might sound a little too basic, but I would like to know if the following statements are correct and if there is a difference between them.

1. From what I understand the bible teaches about one god only.
2. For what I understand the bible teaches about one god only.

This might be odd but I am making things up and those might not be the best examples but I tried. I must also say that I not even know if the second one is grammatical or a real expression. Please don't judge as I haven't hear this kind of expressions in a long time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't really a matter of grammatical correctness. The first sentence makes sense, while the second does not.  The sentence "From what I understand the bible teaches about one god only." translates to "Based off of what I understand the bible teaches about one god only."  The second sentence, however, simply has no real meaning.

I have a guess as to why you are asking this question.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you a speaker of Spanish?  In Spanish, the word "por," which roughly translates to "for," can also mean "because of."  Then you might think that "for" = "because of" and therefore "For what I understand" means "because of what I understand."  However, in English it doesn't work this way.

Bottom line, the first sentence works while the second doesn't.

Comment: You are totally correct I am a Spanish speaker I was trying to translate from it so I thought I would post it to make sure. Thanks

Comment: @ManuelHernandez You're welcome.  I'm actually learning Spanish so I'm glad that I had already learned what "por" means. :P

Comment: And to be honest I was trying to translate from the expression "por lo que yo entiendo la biblia enseña de un dios solamente." if you see I got the "for what I understand" from "por lo que yo entiendo"

Comment: @ManuelHernandez In the same way, It's sort of confusing that you can say "lo que" but not "lo quien."

Comment: Yeah I can't think of an expression in where you can use "lo quien" you right

Comment: Now that I think about it "por" can be translated to "from" and vice versa as in "He attacked me from behind" and "El me atacó por detras" there "por" means "from" but it can not be translated this way all the time as "por" and "from" have many different meanings.

Comment: @ostrichofevil, Shouldn't there be "is"?: From what I understand "is" the bible teaches about one god only.